# Excel not creating full/correct schema

Tags: xml, excel, xml-parsing, vba

I have a working spreadsheet which uses a vba to query a web service and return a tax value and other information.

However, recently I found a bug that stems from excel having not created the schema fully, therefore I am not getting enough of the values I need refreshed in Excel.

Without modifying the vba, I think I can get what I need with the correct schema.

To be clear, the spreadsheet works refreshing the xml, but the bug is that in some search queries, the rate and localrate under response are not matching the staterate and localrate under rate below. So I am returning an incorrect tax rate. Please take a look and see if you can help.

Here is the xml output from the web service:

`<response loccode="1726" localrate="0.036" rate="0.101" code="0"><addressline houselow="700" househigh="700" evenodd="E" street="5TH AVE" state="WA" zip="98104" plus4="3743" period="Q32017" code="1726" rta="Y" ptba="King PTBA" cez="Duwamish"/><rate name="SEATTLE" code="1726" staterate="0.065" localrate="0.036"/></response>`

Here is the url which brings up that xml return:

```
http://dor.wa.gov/AddressRates.aspx?output=xml&addr=700%205th%20Ave&city=Seattle&zip=98104
```

The part of the xml that Excel is not creating schema for is:

```
<rate name="SEATTLE" code="1726" staterate="0.065" localrate="0.036"/>
```

Here is a picture in excel of what that looks like, I have circled the area where Excel is not loading the schema:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Rkb.jpg

And here is the link to download the Excel file:
https://ufile.io/3bejw

Thanks so much for any help, it is greatly appreciated, I am stumped.